# PHP comment box using a txt file

Tags: php, web-applications

I need to make a comment box  using a txt file or anything else that can be queried passively, without using a database server. As I'm fairly new to PHP programming the first idea was to use a text file. The code in general to accomplish this, as far as I can think of logically would be :

```
    <html>
<head></head>
<body>
<form method = "post">
<textarea name = "txt" cols = "25" rows = "5">
Place your comment here ...
</textarea><br><br>
<input type = "submit" value = "Submit" onclick = "<?php
    $com = $_POST["txt"];
    $file = fopen("inrg.txt", "a");
    fwrite($file, "<br>");
    for($i=0; $i <= strlen($com) - 1; $i++)
        {
        fwrite($file, $com[$i]);
        if($i % 37 == 0 && $i != 0)
            fwrite($file, "<br/>");
        }
    fwrite($file, "<br>------------------------------------------");
    fclose($file);
?>">
<br>
</form>
<font face = "Times New Roman"><b><p>Textul introdus este: </p></b></font>
<font face = "Comic Sans MS" color = "red" size = "2" >
<?php
$file = fopen("inrg.txt", "r");
echo fread($file, filesize("inrg.txt"));
fclose($file);
?>
</font>
</body>
</html>
```

Nothing fancy yet, and it does needs some improvements on the esthetics side. The thing is after I submit something in the comment box, it shows properly but if I do reload in the web browser, the last posted comment it's posted again as many times as I reload the page.
Also if there's a way with PHP to make the initial "Place your comment here ..." disappear

Comment: Every time you reload, it's reloading the form data. Before that <form ...> line, you could add add a check to see if any posted data is present. <? if(!isset($_POST)) { %?> <form method="post"> ... </form> <? } %?>

Comment: Part of your refactoring should be removing Comic Sans MS :)

Comment: Oh wow. Just had some serious nostalgia there with the ol' <font> tags :)

Comment: There is no really good answer until South Pole understand how PHP works. Nobody mentioned that he put PHP code into onClick event?! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it redirecting the page to itself:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<form method="post">
  <textarea name="txt" cols="25" rows="5"></textarea>
  <br><br> <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />

  <?php
  if ( isset( $_POST[ 'submit' ] ) ) {
    $com  = $_POST[ "txt" ];
    $file = fopen( "inrg.txt", "a" );
    fwrite( $file, "<br>" );
    for ( $i = 0; $i <= strlen( $com ) - 1; $i++ ) {
      fwrite( $file, $com[ $i ] );
      if ( $i % 37 == 0 && $i != 0 ) fwrite( $file, "<br/>" );
    }
    fwrite( $file, "<br>------------------------------------------" );
    fclose( $file );
   echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location ="";</script>'; // Add here
  }
  ?>

  <br>
</form>
<font face="Times New Roman"><b><p>Textul introdus este: </p></b></font>
<font face="Comic Sans MS" color="red" size="2">
  <?php
  if (file_exists("inrg.txt")) {
  $file = fopen( "inrg.txt", "r" );
  echo fread( $file, filesize( "inrg.txt" ) );
  fclose( $file );
  }
  ?>
</font>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks man. It worked and also this way I've understood one or more things on on how html works in combination with php and scripts in general.

Answer (score 2):

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Example document</title>
      </head>
      <body>
<?php
// the relative path to the file
$fname = "theFile.txt";
// read in the file if present
if(file_exists($fname)) $txt = file_get_contents($fname);

// if the user pushes the submit button
if(isset($_POST["txt"])){
    $txt = $_POST["txt"];   // get the entered content
    file_put_contents($fname,$txt);    // write the content to the file
}
?>
<form method="post" action="#">
<textarea name = "txt" cols = "25" rows = "5">
<?php echo $txt; ?>
</textarea><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
      </body>
    </html>
```

The folder where the script resides must be writable by PHP (=WebServer). This script is critical, no security against cross side scripting hacks. There might be problems concerning line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

anotherpage.php

```
<?php
        if($_POST){ // is a message has been posted

            $fp = fopen('inrg.txt', 'a'); // open the text file and append using the 'a'
            fwrite($fp, $_POST['txt']."\n");
            fclose($fp);
            $message_message_to_user = "Message added to file. Wait a sec and you will be redirected.";
        }

            header("Location: theformpage.php"); // regardless of if there is a post - send the user back to the original page
            exit();
?>
```

theformpage.php

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="anotherpage.php">
    <textarea name = "txt" cols = "25" rows = "5">Place your comment here ...</textarea><br><br>
    <input type = "submit" value="Submit">
    <br>
</form>
<hr />
<?php
    // this reads all of the lines of the file and spits them out on the screen
    $fh = fopen('inrg.txt','r');
    while ($line = fgets($fh)){
        echo nl2br($line); // nl2br() converts new lines to <br>'s
    }
    fclose($fh);

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. It still posts the last comment automatically when I reload the page, but from your post I've learned something new.

Comment: Ah ok - must be the browser im using. You could post to a seperate page, then use the header to get back to this page, that way there is no way at all that a refresh could repost.

Comment: Changed the code - so that there are two files. Give that ago. Should fix your issue for good + try posting a different string of data

Answer (score 0):

let's go by parts:

1) The comment is posted over and over again because you are resubmitting the form on reload. To avoid this, you need to redirect the page after post. This techinque is called `Redirect after Post`. You should search for it, it is interesting.

2) PHP has no way of making the text disappear, because PHP will finish executing when the page finish loading. To do that, you will need to learn Javascript. I'm also learning JavaScript and I thought it was difficult, but take the Simply Javascript book and it will introduce you to JS very nicely.

just for you to know, you have to listen to "onClick" event on your comment box, then call a JS function that will clear the comment box.

Would be something like:

```
... id="thisBoxId" onclick="cleartext('thisBoxID')" >Enter a comment here...<...
```

and the JS:

```
function cleartext( myitem ) {
   myitem.text.value = "";
}
```

Of course, once done, the text will never come back until you reload the page. For making it come back, you should use `onLostFocus` event to refill the text.

Comment: I intend to learn JavaScript in the nearest future, but for now I just needed a quick solution. Thanks for the tip, as now I have a solid lead on how I could accomplish the initial text disappearance.